# Symfony auto deploy with gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: symfony, gitlab, gitlab-ci, devops, lftp

I'm using the `lftp` to transfer file from Gitlab to Cpanel but the volume of `vendor` directory is too big. I want to store the vendor manually and `lftp` replace only changed file or new file of this directory (changes only).
how to do it?

My `gitlab-ci.yml` command is:

`lftp -c "set ftp:ssl-allow no; open -u $FTP_USERNAME,$FTP_PASSWORD $FTP_HOST; mirror -Rev . ./  --ignore-time --parallel=10 --exclude-glob .git* --exclude .git/"`

Comment: I don't understand your problem, do you want to copy vendor directory? or do you want to exclude it?

Comment: I want to copy first one and then copy only edited file like version controls

Comment: Are you able to run commands on your remote server like `composer install`? did you try to use `git archive`?

Comment: @qdequippe no i can not because i have not any access to SSH or etc i can only work with ftp